# Файл занят другим процессом

Tags: файлы, c#

Всем доброго времени суток. Пишу на C#, новичок еще. Решил немного погеймейкерить.

[image: error here]

Вот тут ошибка. Мол, занят другим процессом. По логике, они ничем заняты быть не могут!

Фулл исходники: http://pastebin.com/WmW5wfY3

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас этот файл по завершению работы с ним корректно закрывается? Похоже на то, что при отладке файл был открыт, но не был корректно закрыт.

Comment: Я так же подумал, но не нашел функции .close, или что-то в подобном роде. Не можете подсказать, как его корректно закрыть после создания?

Comment: Вызвать метод Close.

Comment: А, все, понял. Спасибо